# ALT Tag in WP All Import Using PHP Function

Tags: php, wpallimport

I'm trying to pull the alt tag from an image from an xml node titled `<description>`.  Here is the content of the node `<img src="xxx.png" alt="WHAT I WANT TO GRAB">`.  I've tried to create a php function to extract that but it's not working.  Where am I going wrong?  For reference here is the [xml feed](https://www.simplifyingthemarket.com/en/feed?a=10757205-d4511439ebaf95d1ee9a8b34178efd09).

What I'm using to set Alt tag in the import:

```
[get_alt_tags_from_xml({description[1]})]
```

What I'm using for a function:

```
function get_alt_tags_from_xml($content) {
    //The content
    $html = file_get_html($content);
    //Run on all images
    foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
    echo $element->alt . ', ';
    }
```

Comment: It looks like the `<img>` tag is actually wrapped in a CDATA section, so from an XML perspective it is just plain text, and the `find()` method won't work on it. To get this going I think you will need to grab the CDATA contents of the `<description>` element and re-parse that as a XML/HTML, then call `find()` on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Function

Consider using `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath`. Load html and find `img` tags with *xpath*, then extract all attributes. It would be better to use `PHP_EOL` instead of `,`  to join the values.

The function should support extracting both `src` and `alt` attributes to be able to provide two lists of the same size representing the images. [WP All Import](https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/image-metadata/) will use that information as an image data source and for alternative text field population.

```php
function get_img_attrs_from_html( $content, $attribute_name ) {
    if ( empty( $content ) || empty( $attribute_name ) ) {
        return '';
    }
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML( $content );

    $dxp = new DOMXPath( $dom );
    $images = $dxp->query( '//img' );

    $values = array_map( function( $img ) use ( $attribute_name ) {
        return trim( $img->getAttribute( $attribute_name ) );
    }, iterator_to_array( $images ) );

    return join( PHP_EOL, $values );
}
```

#### Template

The `content_encoded` item node from *Simplifyingthemarket* feed is preferable as it contains more images than `description` tag.

Under `Images` section of WP All Import's *Edit Template* page:

1. `Download images hosted elsewhere` should be selected and contain the source list:

- `Enter image URL one per line, or separate them with a` must be blank.
- Value for main input:

```php
[get_img_attrs_from_html({content_encoded[1]},"src")]
```

2. `Scan through post content and import images wrapped in <img> tags` must be *enabled*.
3. `SEO & Advanced Options` -> `Set Alt Text(s)` should be selected and provide the alternative text list:

- `Enter one per line, or separate them with a` must be blank.
- Main input value:

```php
[get_img_attrs_from_html({content_encoded[1]},"alt")]
```

Once these settings are saved the import **can be started**.

#### Test

The attribute extraction function can be tested outside of an import:

```php
$item = <<<XML
<item><content_encoded><![CDATA[
text
<img src="x.png" alt="WHAT I WANT TO GRAB">
<p>
    <img src="no-alt.png">
    <strong>tag</strong>
    <img src="y.png" alt="ANOTHER, AN ATTRIBUTE, SHOULD BE GRABBED">
</p>
]]></content_encoded></item>
XML;
$idom = new DOMDocument;
@$idom->loadXML( $item );
$cnode = ( new DOMXPath( $idom ) )->query( '//content_encoded' );
$content = $cnode->item( 0 )->textContent;

echo get_img_attrs_from_html( $content, 'src' ) . PHP_EOL;
echo get_img_attrs_from_html( $content, 'alt' ). PHP_EOL;
```

```
x.png
no-alt.png
y.png
WHAT I WANT TO GRAB

ANOTHER, AN ATTRIBUTE, SHOULD BE GRABBED
```

Comment: Thank you @hedfol for your detailed response.  Unfortunately I'm still not seeing the expected results.  The images in the media library (and in the posts) do not have an alt tag.  I created a sandbox here where you can see that it's not working. https://nimble-ray-17c83f.instawp.xyz?upass=bXkgYXdlc29tZSBzdHJpbmczNTA2OTg0Mzky

Comment: Thanks, now your use case is much more clear. I've updated the answer. Also I edited and run your `feed` (ID: `2`) in a sandbox which updated the posts and populated the `alt`s. This can be checked in a "Media Library" and on the individual post pages.

Comment: Much appreciated @hedfol works like a charm on live site!